# Can we buy frequent flier miles with Unicoins?

Tags: feature-request, fun

I think a great feature to add would be the option to buy frequent flier miles with Unicons.

That's be great, right???

Comment: Ah, reading this post one month later... confused me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do it if you have the Unicorn Horn American Express card (aka the "Iridium Card," presumably because it could bankrupt Motorola).

Each $1 spent on the card yields 1 Preferred Membership Premier Options Plus Uberpoint. So let's say you spend $100 and get 100 points, the lifetime maximum. You can then purchase Grand Privileges Ultimate Passport Choice Club Supermiles at a 1:1 ratio in 100 mile increments. You get a 10-point bonus just for opening an account, but due to a bug the bonus is converted based on the current exchange between the euro and the Supermiles' native currency, the Lithuanian lita, yielding only 3 points. But hey, a bonus is a bonus, and it's totally worth it because GCCPUP Supermiles is running a promotion with Delta Air Lines' Skymiles with an unbelievable 1:100 exchange ratio— minus 10 points for international processing, so try to do it in a single transaction.

You can then do a Points.com conversion at a 10:1 exchange, which earns you a 1-point bonus with coupon code CANTPOSSIBLYBEWORTHTHETRANSACTIONCOSTSBETTERTHINGSU022, noting that it's not UO22 but U022 (as in "you aught two two"). Points.com has a partnership with Union Pacific Boxcar Hobo Priority Bonus Circle Pass "beancans," so you can transfer the points to beancans at a 100:1 ratio. It's a big reduction, but we're after unipoints, and let's face it, Zimbabwean dollars are worth a lot more than Skymiles these days.

Now, for the conversion. IF you are Royal Titanium Worshipful Star God-Emperor Elite on AirMegamerger, you can use beancans to gain admission to any VIP Olympian Galactica Inner Sanctum Lounge in the Central Asia or Antarctica regions. A one-time pass is only 3 beancans. But only the agents assigned to the clubs handle unipoint transactions. You can convert your remaining beancans to unipoints at a 10:1 ratio, minus 100 beancans for the transaction fee.

It's totally worth it.